# Passing an object using React useContext() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a view with a list of items. When I click on one of the items I want to have the panel display all the details of the item that was clicked.

Here is the Context File I wrote

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ActivityPreviewContext = React.createContext();
const ActivityPreviewUpdateContext = React.createContext();

export function useActivityPreview() {
    return useContext(ActivityPreviewContext);
}

export function useActivityPreviewUpdate() {
    return useContext(ActivityPreviewUpdateContext);
}

export function ActivityPreviewProvider({ children }) {
    const [activityPreview, setActivityPreview] = useState();

    function activityPreviewUpdate(data) {
        setActivityPreview(data);
    }

    return (
        <ActivityPreviewContext.Provider value={activityPreview}>
            <ActivityPreviewUpdateContext.Provider value={activityPreviewUpdate}>
                    {children}
            </ActivityPreviewUpdateContext.Provider>
        </ActivityPreviewContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

I am wrapping this in my routes like this. This seems to work fine so far

```
<Route path="/home">
   <ActivityPreviewProvider>
        <SideMenu />
        <HomeView />
    </ActivityPreviewProvider>
</Route>
```

HomeView is where I have long lists showing up. You will notice openPeekPanel() function is calling `activityPreviewUpdate(e.currentTarget.id);` this works, but trying to pass an object gives me an error.

this what I've tried:
`activityPreviewUpdate(e.currentTarget.id);` WORKS: passing a number or string
`activityPreviewUpdate([1,2,3]);` WORKS: passing an array
`activityPreviewUpdate({a:123, b:456});` BREAKS: passing an array

I would like to pass the entire object full of data so I could add it into the side panel.

You could view the code below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import ThumbnailGroup from './ThumbnailGroup';
import PanelPreview from './PanelPreview';
import { useActivityPreview, useActivityPreviewUpdate } from '../context/ActivityPreviewContext';

const fakeData = [
    {
        id: 100,
        type: "video",
        title: "My Title",
        duration: 2,
        questions: 4,
        image: "https://picsum.photos/seed/1/200/150"
    },
    {
        id: 101,
        type: "video",
        title: "My Title",
        duration: 2,
        questions: 4,
        image: "https://picsum.photos/seed/2/200/150"
    }
]

const HomeView = (props) => {

    const history = useHistory();
    const [peekActive, setPeekActive] = useState(false);
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(0);
    
    const activityPreview = useActivityPreview();
    const activityPreviewUpdate = useActivityPreviewUpdate();

    const closePeekPanel = () => {
        let section_ele = document.querySelector("section");
        section_ele.classList.remove("activePanel");
        setPeekActive(false);
    }
    
    const openPeekPanel = (e) => {

        activityPreviewUpdate(e.currentTarget.id);

        let section_ele = document.querySelector("section");
        section_ele.classList.add("activePanel");
        setPeekActive(true);
    }

    return (
        <section id="homeView" className="panelView"> 
            <div id="contentArea">
                <ThumbnailGroup name="favorite" data={fakeData} title="Favorited recently" onClick={openPeekPanel} />
            </div>
            {peekActive && <PanelPreview onClosePanel={closePeekPanel} />}
            
        </section>
    );
};

export default HomeView;
```

At the moment I am only printing the ID in the side panel.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Card from './Card';
import Icon from './Icon';
import { useActivityPreview, ActivityPreviewProvider } from '../context/ActivityPreviewContext';

const PanelPreview = (props) => {
    //hooks
    const history = useHistory();
    const activityPreview = useActivityPreview();

    return (
        <Card id="panelPreview">
          <div className="panelHeader">
            {
                <p>{activityPreview}</p>
            }   
          </div>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default PanelPreview;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because React doesn't render JSON in HTML, only strings.
`e.currentTarget.id` renders that string and `[1,2,3]` is joined and rendered as `123`.

If you plan on accepting an object, you should consider selecting that property in the `p` element. `<p>{activityPreview.a}</p>` would display`123` without errors.

Although `JSON.Stringify({a:123, b:456})` might be what you're looking for, to display the entire object as-is, without breaking.