# Why is the data undefined in react component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I'm trying to reproduce a simple example code of react-qr-scanner, but in the code below as I try to embed result in the p tag I get an error, saying objects cannot be embedded inside that. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import QrReader from 'react-qr-scanner';

class Scan extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            result : 'Hold QR Code steady and clear to scan',
        }
        this.previewStyle = {
            height : 700,
            width : 1000,
            display : 'flex',
            justifyContent : "center",
        }
        this.camStyle = {
            display : 'flex',
            justifyContent : 'center',
            marginTop : '-50px',
        }
        this.textStyle= {
            fontSize : '30px',
            "text-align" : 'center',
            marginTop : '-50px',
        }
        this.handleScan = this.handleScan.bind(this);
    }

    handleScan(data) {
        this.setState({
            result : data,
        });
    }

    handleError(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    
    render() {
        return (
        <>
        <div className="stream-container" >
        <QrReader
        delay={100}
        onError={this.handleError}
        onScan={this.handleScan}
        />
        </div>
        <p style={this.resultStyle}>
            {this.state.result}   //here error occurs saying I cannot embed it inside here
        </p>
        </>
        );
    }
}

export default Scan;
```

The docs of react-qr-scanner has this exact example, so why isn't it working on mine? Please help.

Comment: I'm guessing result is a JSON. See if this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947983/6421664

Comment: It'll depend on what you scan, and it seems like you're scanning something React can't render, try `this.state.result?.toString()` instead. Also if you put a breakpoint to `handleScan` or print `data` to console you'll see what React is struggling with exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In the function of handleScan, data is an object, 'Objects are not valid as a React child'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your fuctions with arrow -

```
handleScan = (data) => {
    this.setState({
        result: data,
    });
}

handleError = (err) => {
    console.log(err);
}
```